# C++, чтение Excel файла без привязки к версии Excel

Tags: c++, excel

Написал библиотеку на C++, согласно методу, используемому [тут](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ahazel/EXCEL_C++.pdf) (страница 59)
Библиотека работает на моем компьютере (У меня Excel 2013), но не работает у другого человека (Excel 2016). Как можно реализовать универсально, чтобы под каждый Excel не перекомпилировать?

Comment: Никак, формат вполне себе может отличаться.

Comment: Тем более, ваш пример линкуется с конкретной версией библиотек MS Office.

Comment: Есть способ отвязаться. Это использование ф-ций `LoadLibrary` и `GetProcAddress` - это позволит использовать любые поддерживаемые программистом версии DLL. Далее. У нас проблема получается с импортом DCOM. Суть проблемы в том, что есть некие файлы описаний, который и позволяют писать в теле программы вызовы к Экселю напрямую (т.е. так - `Excel::_ApplicationPtr XL;`). Получается, что нужно или найти эти описания (TLB-файлы) для всех поддерживаемых версий Экселя и внедрить их в программу. Либо вручную генерировать все вызовы (это та еще морока) ... брррр. Код будет выглядеть мерзко - примерно

Comment: так : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/111466/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ - никак.

Поясню.

Вариантов как сделать работу с файлами Excel принципиально два:
- либо использовать готовые библиотеки;
- либо все делать самому.

В первом случае, Вы ограничены возможностями этих библиотек. Если их разработчик не вложил в нее функционал по работе с форматом Excel версии XXX, то его и взять неоткуда получается. Библиотек такого типа полно. Посоветовать какая лучше не могу, т.к. нужно конкретизировать задачу.

Еще более весело, когда для работы с Экселем используются компоненты пакета Офис (ес-но, он при этом должен быть установлен). Это допустимо, но тогда нужно определять версию установленного пакета и работать с ним строго по его API. И зачастую таскать Эксель для выполнения примитивной работы с Эксель файлами излишне.

Если делать самому, то это все пахнет очень большими сложностями - старые эксель файлы были в бинарном формате и тоже разных несовместимых версий. С новыми попроще (которые xslx) - можно файл распаковать, разобрать и незнакомые ключевые слова проигнорировать. Из плюсов - Вы не зависит от того какая версия Excel установлена у пользователя.

Но подчеркну, что если выйдет Excel, скажем, 2020 и там опять радикально поменяют формат хранения данных,то программу все равно придется переписывать.